# I cannot redirect or hide Get-VM output

Tags: powershell

So I have a line of code to retrieve the VMID from a hyper-v vm.  Running on Server 2016 so it should be at least Powershell 5.0.

```
[string]$vmid = (Get-VM $VMName).VMID
```

Pulls out the ID just how I need.  The problem is the script also prints out the full result of `Get-VM`. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to mute or redirect it.

`[void]` doesn't work cause I'm pulling it into a string.

`*> $null`, `2> $null`, `1> $null` all do nothing, and I've tried both in the parenthesis and after the expression.

Piping to `Out-Null` has no effect either in those locations.

Any idea how I'm supposed to hide this?  I really don't need all this info.

Answer (score 0):

On my hyper-v server I had to run

```
$vmid = (Get-VM $VMName).VMid.Guid
```

to save only the string to variable

The above command works for me, so it's probably somewhere else in your code that you are getting the unwanted output?

Comment: I've commented every line out after that line and it still has the same result.  I just tried .guid but it seemed to have no change.

Comment: maybe try
    'Get-Variable' cmd to see what your shell environment variables are set to.  Compare with a clean OS install.  Perhaps you have verbose/debug mode enabled?

Comment: I don't appear to,  AFAIK.  At any rate, i seem to have resolved the issue by creating a $vm and setting it to Get-VM, then simply going $vm.VMID.GUID in the subsequent line.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of the above, I ended up defining a $vm variable when creating the VM, then using it in the operations below.

`$vm = New-VM ...`

`...`

`[string]$vmid = $vm.VMID.GUID`